# Find if tab li has the active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnRew').hide();
  
  $('.btnFw').click(function() {
    //$('.nav-tabs .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    $('.nav-tabs, .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    checky();
  });

  $('.btnRew').click(function() {
    //$('.nav-tabs .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    $('.nav-tabs, .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    checky();
  });


  function checky() {
    if (document.getElementById("screen").classList.contains('active')) {
      console.log('its active');
      $('.btnRew').hide();
    } else {
      console.log('not active');
      $('.btnRew').show();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://scdcare.org/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://allyoucan.cloud/cdn/icofont/1.0.1/icofont.css" rel="stylesheet"/><section id="milestones" class="milestones">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-title">
        <p class="display-body">Milestones | <span class="display-body2">Select an icon to read more about milestones and personal experiences</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link active" id="screen-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#screen" role="tab" aria-controls="screen" aria-selected="true"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon1.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="pen-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#pen" role="tab" aria-controls="pen" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon2.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="immun-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#immun" role="tab" aria-controls="immun" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon3.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="hu-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#hu" role="tab" aria-controls="hu" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon4.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="tcd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tcd" role="tab" aria-controls="tcd" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon5.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="day-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#day" role="tab" aria-controls="day" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon6.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="mri-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#mri" role="tab" aria-controls="mri" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon7.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="school-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#school" role="tab" aria-controls="school" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon8.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="sports-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#sports" role="tab" aria-controls="sports" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon9.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="trans-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#trans" role="tab" aria-controls="trans" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon10.png" /></a> </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 anti-pad">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent"> 
                    <div id="mileButtons">
                    <a class="btn btnRew"><i class="icofont-simple-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btnFw"><i class="icofont-simple-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="screen" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="screen-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Genetic Screening</span></div>
                          <div class="col-lg-3 text-right">  
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pen" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pen-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Penicillin</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                         
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="immun" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="immun-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Immunizations</span></div>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="hu" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="hu-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Hydroxyurea</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tcd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tcd-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">TCD</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="day" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="day-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Starting Daycare</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="mri" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mri-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">MRI’s and Neuropsych Testing</span></div>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="school" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="school-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Starting School</span></div>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sports" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sport-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Starting Sports</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                         
                          
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="trans" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="trans-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-9"><span class="jumboMile">Eventual Transition From Pediatric Care</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        
                       
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I'm trying to determine whether or not the tab is active. I can get it to work after two clicks of the button, but not the first. It's like my code it not registering the first click. I'm trying to determine if the first `li` with an ID of `screen` is active. If it is, I want to hide the `btnRew` button. Again this works after I click the `btnFw` button twice, but not after the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain that .. the `a` with `#` href it takes few msecond/seconds to take effects it may be not noticeable with human eyes but still has a delay to make the action .. if you add a little bit of time using `setTimeout()` like the next example you'll got the point

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnRew').hide();
  
  $('.btnFw').click(function() {
    //$('.nav-tabs .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    $('.nav-link.active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    checky();
  });
  
  $('.btnRew').click(function() {
    //$('.nav-tabs .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    $('.nav-link.active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    checky();
  });
  
 
});

function checky() {
    setTimeout( function (){
    if ($("#screen").hasClass('active')) {
      console.log('its active');
      $('.btnRew').hide();
    } else {
      console.log('not active');
      $('.btnRew').show();
    }
    } , 500);
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://scdcare.org/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://allyoucan.cloud/cdn/icofont/1.0.1/icofont.css" rel="stylesheet"/><section id="milestones" class="milestones">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-title">
        <p class="display-body">Milestones | <span class="display-body2">Select an icon to read more about milestones and personal experiences</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link active" id="screen-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#screen" role="tab" aria-controls="screen" aria-selected="true"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon1.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="pen-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#pen" role="tab" aria-controls="pen" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon2.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="immun-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#immun" role="tab" aria-controls="immun" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon3.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="hu-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#hu" role="tab" aria-controls="hu" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon4.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="tcd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tcd" role="tab" aria-controls="tcd" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon5.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="day-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#day" role="tab" aria-controls="day" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon6.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="mri-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#mri" role="tab" aria-controls="mri" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon7.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="school-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#school" role="tab" aria-controls="school" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon8.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="sports-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#sports" role="tab" aria-controls="sports" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon9.png" /></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" id="trans-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#trans" role="tab" aria-controls="trans" aria-selected="false"><img src="assets/img/Milestones_Icon10.png" /></a> </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 anti-pad">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent"> 
                    <div id="mileButtons">
                    <a class="btn btnRew"><i class="icofont-simple-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btnFw"><i class="icofont-simple-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="screen" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="screen-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Genetic Screening</span></div>
                          <div class="col-lg-3 text-right">  
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pen" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pen-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Penicillin</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                         
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="immun" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="immun-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Immunizations</span></div>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="hu" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="hu-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Hydroxyurea</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tcd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tcd-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">TCD</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="day" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="day-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Starting Daycare</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="mri" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mri-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">MRI’s and Neuropsych Testing</span></div>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="school" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="school-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Starting School</span></div>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sports" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sport-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-7"><span class="jumboMile">Starting Sports</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                         
                          
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 pb-2">
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="trans" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="trans-tab">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                          <div class="col-lg-9"><span class="jumboMile">Eventual Transition From Pediatric Care</span></div>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                          
                          <div class="col-lg-4"> <span class="jumboSub">Lorem</span>
                            <p>Blue sky thinking. I am dead inside what do you feel you would bring to the table if you were hired for this position, nor cannibalize, or pipeline, for get all your ducks in a row.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Row-->
                        
                       
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="jumboQ"> <span class="jumboSub">Laura | Age 7 | SS</span>
                              <p>"Open door policy draw a line in the sand. Back of the net low hanging fruit. Product market fit. Streamline forcing function accountable talk at the end of the day."</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

So it will be much easier to check for the first `nav-link` active class instead of check the `#screen` element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnRew').hide();
  
  $('.btnFw').click(function() {
    $('.nav-link.active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    checky();
  });
  
  $('.btnRew').click(function() {
    $('.nav-link.active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    checky();
  });
  
 
});

function checky() {
    if ($(".nav-tabs .nav-link:eq(0)").hasClass('active')) {
      console.log('its active');
      $('.btnRew').hide();
    } else {
      console.log('not active');
      $('.btnRew').show();
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (document.getElementById("screen").classList.contains('active')) {
  console.log('its active');
  $('.btnRew').hide();
}
```

Please try this to check if your element with id "screen" has a class "active".

Comment: Same thing, I have to click it twice.

Comment: I see you have already set the class to active for your required div. Do you have a working example where we can take a look ?

Comment: You see an example at https://scdcare.org/, the milestones section

Comment: $('.nav-tabs .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click'); Change this to  $('.nav-tabs, .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click'); To pass your classnames separated by commas(,) - same for the .next('li')
or you can pass two calls for each class name separately. I am still looking at your page and will try to repro this part. If you can do that on jsfiddle it'd be easier to debug there

Comment: Made the changes, same thing. I'll try to make a fiddle